# Deduce the Cubic Spline formula based on Lagrange Interpolation Polynomial

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

A question asks to deduce the cubic spline formula based on the langrange interpolation polynomial.

I really don't even know where to begin.

Im thinking I need to start using the linear Langrange piecewise function and start with that known property. But how would I get from there to a poly in the third degree?